# VueJS: best way to toggle between two instances of the same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, timeout

Lets say I have `foo.vue` that I import into the parent as components named `a` and `b` and displayed according to a variable `show`

Now from the parent if I switch between components `a` and `b` without setting the `show = null` I get all sorts of child state errors.

So I set `show` to `null` before setting it to the corresponding vue component like this

```
this.show = null
this.show = a // or b
```

but this does not work. component ends up with state of the previous. This is verified even on props that are not updated.

I made it work using `timeout`

```
toggle(show){
   this.show = null
   let that = this
   setTimeout(() => {
      that.show = show
   }, 200)
 }
```

Is there a better way ? That is not elegant to me

What I understand is that what is going on inside the child does not matter if the parents tells it to switch it should go from blank slate and rebuild ? But in my case it is not the case. Is there anything that could cause my issue ?

setting to `null` forces a hard refresh somehow ?

My child component is complex with ajax call to retrieve a list but nothing out of the ordinary.

parent code

```
<template>
<div id="userAreaEventWrapper">
    <div class="userarea-submenu">
        <div v-on:click="toggle(comps.eventForm)" class='button-base-out'>
            <div :class="isSelected(comps.eventForm)">
                New Event
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-on:click="toggle(comps.events)" class='button-base-out'>
            <div :class="isSelected(comps.events)">
                My Events
            </div>
        </div>
      <div v-on:click="toggle(comps.eventsAttending)" class='button-base-out'>
        <div :class="isSelected(comps.eventsAttending)">
          Attending
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <EventForm v-if="show === comps.eventForm" @created="toggle(comps.events)" :mode="'create'"></EventForm>
    <Events ref="events" :mode="currentMode" v-if="show === comps.events" @noResults="toggle(comps.eventForm)" :attending="false"></Events>
    <AttendingEvents ref="attending" :mode="'home'" v-if="show === comps.eventsAttending" :attending="true"></AttendingEvents>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const EventForm = () => import( './event-form.vue')
const Events = () => import( './events.vue')
const AttendingEvents = () => import( './events.vue')

export default {
    name: "UserEventComponent",
    components:{
        EventForm,
        Events,
        AttendingEvents
    },
    data(){
        return{
            comps:{
              eventForm:1,
              events:2,
              eventsAttending:3
            },
            show: 2,
            currentMode:'user',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle(show){
          this.show = null
          let that = this
          setTimeout(() => {
            that.show = show
          }, 200)
        },
        isSelected(n){
          return n === this.show ? 'button-base-in button-base-in-hover' : 'button-base-in'
        },

    },
}
 </script>
```

child

fetch api on `mounted()`

```
  mounted() {
    this.currentMode = this.mode
    if(this.resumeData && this.resumeData.slug){
       this.selectedSlug = this.resumeData.slug
    } else {
       this.resume(this.resumeData)
       this.getEvents()
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your ;problem. It's unclear what it exactly looks like. *but this does not work because JS is async right* - it's async or sync, why it doesn't work depends on your case.

Comment: Yes ok that was not a good statement, I know js can be async or sync. But this is not really related to JS I think but more the vue way ? I don't see anywhere on the net saying that you should use promises or async or use timeout to keep states separated

Comment: Please, post the code, not describe it, this is required by SO rules to avoid ambiguity. You can see why this important, the user has already posted the answer that didn't solve the problem because it doesn't fit the actual code you have.

Comment: you want me to post the child too ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41086548/3478010

Comment: @Roamer-1888 seems like it fits the symptoms but I don't understand it very well yet. You might be onto it.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , the link describes what exactly is needed, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If this means that the question should contain full code for parent and child components, then that's it. Currently the question makes sense only for you because you've seen your own code. Other users didn't and can only guess. From my understanding, you may need `key` for different instances of the same component, but it's unclear if it's so.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes that was it, from the post you linked I just had to add :key="someUniqueValue" to each child component and no need for timeout anymore !! thank you. Please post an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Sam, I'm happy that you have accepted Estus Flask's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part doesn't serve a good purpose:

```
const Events = () => import( './events.vue')
const AttendingEvents = () => import( './events.vue')
```

The core feature of JavaScript modules (this includes ES modules) are evaluated only once on first import, `import( './events.vue')` resolves to the same component. It gives a better idea whats going on when a component is used under a single name.

What happens on `show` update is that there's 1 events component instance in the same place in component hierarchy, so it's not re-mounted and just receives a set of new props, specified in `<Events>` and `<AttendingEvents>` respectively.

Sibling instances of the same component should be distinguished by `key`:

```
<Events ref="events" key="events" ... ></Events>
<Events ref="attending" key="attending" ... ></Events>
```

It is used most times with `v-for` but also applicable to all directives that affect component hierarchy - `v-if`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you call the api to change the data in the component from the `mounted` hook.

if you "switch" components without the `timeout` what happens is that the child component is already rendered and alive but it changes the props. when you call `timeout` you change `this.show = null` before which causes the component to not be rendered, and then inside the `timeout` you change it to the correct component and the component is rendered again which fires the `mounted` hook.

The best solution to this problem is to use `watcher` inside the child component that will change for every component instance (some sort of id). and call the api from the watcher.

so for example add a prop of id for example and watch it:

```
props: {
  id: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
},
watchers: {
  id() {
     this.currentMode = this.mode
    if(this.resumeData && this.resumeData.slug){
       this.selectedSlug = this.resumeData.slug
    } else {
       this.resume(this.resumeData)
       this.getEvents()
    }
  },
  immediate: true
}
```

the `immediate: true` fires the watcher at the mount of the component as well so you don't need to call it again inside `mounted` hook.