# Vue3 Composition API: Multiple instances of same Component share state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm working my way through Vue 3 and the Composition API and I can't figure out how to make multiple instances of the same component work.

```
<Loader />
<Loader />
<Loader />
```

Loader.vue

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            status: null
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the first Loader ist done and sets `status`, the other `<Loader />` components work as expected.

However, when using Composition API like follows, the first `<Loader />` that is done sets the status und all the other Components use that new status instead working with there own variables.

```
const status = ref(null)
```

How can I achieve this behaviour in Vue3 with Composition API?

I found an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086548/ensure-multiple-instances-of-the-same-component-have-non-shared-state) about a similar problem but this doesn't help with Composition API. I guess, it's related to state management of the components. Also, the official docs don't help.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem if it persists. It looks like you accidentally used global state https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html instead of local one. `const status = ref(null)` is supposed to be inside setup function or `script setup` in case you need it to be local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not seeing how you are passing the status into the Loader.  You should have a property on each of the loaders like this.

```
<Loader :status="status"/>
<Loader :status="status"/>
<Loader :status="status"/>
```

And then in Loader you'll have to declare the props

```
const props = defineProps(['status']);
```

Now when you update the status in the parent it should carry through to all the instances.

If that isn't the issue you are having, another kind of similar issue that often will come up with you have several divs with the same name is the lack of a unique ID.  To fix that you'll want to do something like this:

```
<Loader :status="status" key="1"/>
<Loader :status="status" key="2"/>
<Loader :status="status" key="3"/>
```

That is normally an issue with foreach loops, but it could be an issue that you are having as well in this case.

Comment: Thank you, this helps! It still seems to be a workaround and there might be cases where this is not preferable, but in my case this works. But still, I appreciate if anyone knows if there's a way to get the behaviour from Options API.

Comment: The part about id looks irrelevant. There's no such requirement in Vue. There may be a need for `key` but only for dynamically created comp instances

Comment: @EstusFlask, yup, somewhere along the way I seem to have switched from using key to id, but reading the docs it sounds like they may have a similar effect. I was thinking that since he is essentially creating several identical components he may be running into the same state issues that can crop up without a key. But alas it sounds like the first part worked.

Comment: @fabian.bhl It's really a workaround. This would be how you pass state between parent and child components normally. If you state management were more complex you might look at something like Pina which is the supported state manager. However, thats rather overkill for your use case.